# Is it possible to fill in the background color so there's no white? I am using the clip-path css property in this screenshot

Tags: css, layout, styled-components, clip-path

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRpxQ.jpg

Codepen: https://codepen.io/yongelee/pen/eVobRd

I want to make the background have no white, so basically have that white space as the color of the next block's background. But unfortunately when I clip-path, the div doesn't change from a rectangle to a trapezoid!

My code (JSX):

```
<Wrapper>
<HeroBlock>
  <h1>hi</h1>
  <h4>hihi</h4>
</HeroBlock>
<IntroBlock>
  <h1>heyyy</h1>
  <h4>YO??</h4>
</IntroBlock>
<SkillsBlock>
  <h1>Heyy</h1>
  <h4>okkk</h4>
</SkillsBlock>
</Wrapper>

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
`
const HeroBlock = styled.div`
  background: skyblue;
  height: 50vh;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
`
const IntroBlock = styled.div`
  background: orange;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 90%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 90%);
`
const SkillsBlock = styled.div`
  background: red;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
`
```

Using styled-components for this.

Comment: Could you please edit the post and add a snippet of the code?

Comment: @JuanTheron There is code, the <Wrapper> and <HeroBlock> and others are divs and the styles are under them

Comment: I can see that, but a snippet makes it easier for me to edit the code and come up with a solution

Comment: @JuanTheron https://codepen.io/yongelee/pen/eVobRd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply consider some negative margin like this:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.hero {
  background: skyblue;
  height: 50vh;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
}

.intro {
  margin-top: -40px;
  background: orange;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 90%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 90%);
}

.skills {
  margin-top: -40px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hero">
    <h1>Hey</h1>
    <h4>heyy</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="intro">
    <h1>Hii</h1>
    <h4>Yoo</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="skills">
    <h1>One</h1>
    <h4>Noooo</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok Here is what I came up with:

```css
h1 {
  margin-top:0;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
.hero_cont {
  background-color:orange;
}
.hero {
  padding-top:21px;
    background: skyblue;
  height: 50vh;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
}
.intro_cont {
  background-color:red;
}
.intro {
  padding-top:21px;
    background: orange;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 90%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 90%);
}
.skills_cont {
  background-color:transparent;
}
.skills {
  padding-top:21px;
    background: red;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='hero_cont'>
    <div class="hero">
      <h1>Hey</h1>
      <h4>heyy</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='intro_cont'>
    <div class="intro">
      <h1>Hii</h1>
      <h4>Yoo</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='skills_cont'>
    <div class="skills">
      <h1>One</h1>
      <h4>Noooo</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i'd like to add clip path into div not stricte to section. I can clip div, and i can make linear-gradient on section, so section up to clip-path is for example red, so top of my section where is clip is also red, and bottom blue, bc next section gonna be blue. It seperate nice content :D

```css
.section-stats {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(247, 247, 247), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5rem 0;
// this is element which we want to clip
  &--clip {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10rem 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to right bottom,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6),
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
      ),
      url("../../img/renovation-tools.jpeg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 90%, 50% 100%, 0 90%, 0 0, 50% 10%);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 80%, 50% 100%, 0 80%, 0 0, 50% 20%);
  }
  
  & .row {
    margin: 20rem 0 10rem;
  }


  &--icon {
    font-size: 10rem;
    color: $color-secondary-light;

    @include respond(tab-port) {
      font-size: 6rem;
    }
  }

  &--count {
    display: block;
    font-size: 7rem;
    color: $color-secondary-light;
    margin-top: -2rem;
    @include respond(tab-port) {
      font-size: 5rem;
    }
  }
  &--sub {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translateY(0.8rem);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="section-stats ">
        <div class="section-stats--clip u-flex">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1-of-3 u-center-text">
              <i class="lni lni-apartment section-stats--icon"></i>
              <span class="section-stats--count"
                >2<span class="section-stats--sub">3</span>8</span
              >
              <h3 class="heading-tertiary heading-white">COMPLETED PROJECTS</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1-of-3 u-center-text">
              <i class="lni lni-apartment section-stats--icon"></i>
              <span class="section-stats--count"
                >7<span class="section-stats--sub">5</span>1</span
              >
              <h3 class="heading-tertiary heading-white">COMPLETED PROJECTS</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1-of-3 u-center-text">
              <i class="lni lni-apartment section-stats--icon"></i>
              <span class="section-stats--count"
                >7<span class="section-stats--sub">5</span>1</span
              >
              <h3 class="heading-tertiary heading-white">COMPLETED PROJECTS</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```